# Can't Logout and redirect to LoginPage when using Firebase/ Google Sign-in in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am working on implementing a Flutter app that uses Firebase authentication as well as Google-Sign. I have successfully gotten firebaseauth working to sign-in/signout without issue. based on the authstate change, I direct to main page or login page. I then implemented Google Sign-in, which auto-signs in user to firebase.

This worked and I got the necessary permissions to be prompted,etc. But when I click to logout, the app doesn't redirect to login screen. I Am calling the await firebaseAuth.instance.Signout() ...and I believe it does remove the user..but it doesn't redirect. Then, when I try to sign-in again, nothing happens.

I have tried many different variations of logging in..I can't seem to figure out why it won't redirect on logout.

This is my Sign-in Logic which signs into Google and firebase:

```
    try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
       await _googleSignIn.signIn();
   final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
notifyListeners();
}
```

This is my logic in main.dart to redirect to appropriate page:

```
    home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return HomePage();
          } else {
            return Login();
          }
        },
      )
```

This is my logic to Signout()

```
   Future<void> signOut() async {
   await _firebaseAuth.signOut().catchError((error){
   print(error.toString());
   });
   }
```

In my case, I don't want to log the user out of Google, just my app.
But I cannot figure out why this doesn't redirect. It worked correctly when I was using the standard firebase sign-in with email/password.

Comment: Tray to add notifyListeners(); after await _firebaseAuth.signOut()

Comment: yea, already tried that...no difference. I actually also found out, it doesn't logout the firebase user here...after I click logout, I go back to existing screen and the user is still logged in?  very stange. Any other ideas?

Comment: @mikehennessy not related to the question,how did you setup google signin .i have filled in the consent form and i still cant get it to work

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging around, it turns out that if you are calling SignOut() from the sideDrawer component, you can't just call Signout. you need to do this. Solved it for me.

```
    FlatButton(
        child: Text('Logout'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
          Provider.of<Auth>(context).signOut();
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Oh man thanks a lot. After a lot of hours found your answer. I am also using a side drawer with sign-out button

Answer (score 2):

This works in [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state). I used `authStateChanges()` method on a FirebaseAuth instance and [Navigator](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics#2-navigate-to-the-second-route-using-navigatorpush).

- `authStateChanges()` method allows you to get the user's authentication state.

> Firebase Auth enables you to subscribe in realtime to this state via a
> Stream. Once called, the stream provides an immediate event of the
> user's current authentication state, and then provides subsequent
> events whenever the authentication state changes.

- `Navigator` is for navigating to `main.dart`

> To switch to a new route, use the Navigator.push() method. The push()
> method adds a Route to the stack of routes managed by the Navigator.

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'menu.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MyApp()
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'TestApp',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: 
        StreamBuilder<auth.User>(
          stream: auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<auth.User> snapshot) { 
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              print("There is a user logged in");
              return HomePage();
            }
            else {
              return LoginPage();
            }
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Sign out using Firebase Authentication

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
   await _firebaseAuth.signOut().catchError((error){
       print(error.toString());
   });
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only to do singOut on _googleSignIn like this:

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
   await _firebaseAuth.signOut().catchError((error){
       print(error.toString());
   });
   await _googleSignIn.signOut();
}
```

Comment: So, I've just tried this https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial using Bloc that is similar, take a look, mayme it could help you.

Comment: I don't see anything there that identifies any issues...this is really strange.